# CustomValidator to validate multiple controls

Tags: c#, .net, customvalidator

Is there a way to have the custom validator take the input from two controls, say for example two check boxes and make sure that only one is checked?

Or am I going about this all wrong, and more importantly if I am could you point me in the right direction?

Even if this is the wrong direction actually I would like to know how to do this in case I run into a situation where it is applicable, that is if it's possible.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: If you want one to always be checked, why not use a radio button group?  If both can be unchecked, then this is not adequate (unless you provide a third option in the group which is none)

Comment: Unfortunately it's a design decision that's out of my control.  They weren't happy with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX Control Toolkit has an exclusive checkbox list.  I agree with the need for it, as radio buttons cannot be de-selected like checkboxes can.

If you're looking to roll a custom validator, it sounds like you either do it server side, at which point you can do whatever logic you want in the code behind.  Conversely, you can roll your own javascript to enforce it.

Comment: I'll look into using the AJAX Control Toolkit, and let you know how it works.  I tried using my own JavaScript but for whatever reason, the stuff that I wrote and examples I found on Google were not working.  I would select one check box, then to test I would select the other, and they would both stay checked and I wasn't even able to uncheck them by clicking them again.

Comment: The control toolkit didn't work for two reasons. 1) We are still runing 2.0 here with no hope of upgrading anytime soon, and the 2.0 version of the toolkit is no longer available.  2) I have to use standard html input tags rather than the checkbox controls.
So it looks like I will have to write some JavaScript to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that only one of two checkboxes are checked, you are using the wrong control.

Use a radio button to setup an exclusive selection.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a decision that was out of my control.  The people who requested the report disliked the radio buttons and wanted check boxes. :/ Otherwise yes this would be the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mitchel that a RadioButton seems more appropriate.

But have you tried hooking up a CompareValidator and set it to validate  UnEqual?

Comment: This seems like a good solution as well, I'll look into this and the AJAX Toolkit's exclusive checkbox list and come back to update with checkmarks and upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog article about this very thing.

http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2010/10/11/ASPNET-CustomValidator-that-validates-multiple-controls-using-both-Server-Side-and-Client-Side-scripting

Combines both Client Side and Server Side validation and re-validates

Comment: The page is now located [here](http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2010/10/11/ASPNET-CustomValidator-that-validates-multiple-controls-using-both-Server-Side-and-Client-Side-scripting)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on a similar problem.  The way I worked around this issue, was to create a validator for each of my controls, and to link them to the same method that ensures whatever your validation restrictions are.

```
protected void validator1_ServerValidate(...){
  myValidationMethod(...);
}

protected void validator2_ServerValidate(...){
  myValidationMethod(...);
}
```

It works, but it's pretty ugly IMO